# R - Trouble looping over a dataframe and factorising variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with >100 columns, all of which are INTs.

I have subsetted some columns which I would like to factorise, allowing me to conduct an ANOVA, say

```
my_variables_list = headers[grep('independent', headers)]
```

Now I would like to loop over all these variables and factorise:

```
for (i in my_variables_list) {
    df$i = as.factor(df$i)
}
```

However this doesn't work - no error message is returned, but also no changes are made to the df. Similarly, if I try to run a single line of this it also fails.

```
df$my_variables_list[10] <- as.factor(df$my_variables_list[10])
```

Comment: could you provide some of your data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `[]` operators to subset your dataframe within the for loop:

```
for (i in my_variables_list) {
    df[,i] = as.factor(df[,i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example on `iris`  avoiding the loop. We first look for the patter `Sepal` or `Sepal` in the colnames of `iris`, then convert those columns to factor with `lapply`

```
my_variables_list = grep('Petal|Sepal', colnames(iris))
iris[, my_variables_list] <- lapply(iris[, my_variables_list], as.factor)
```

or on you data.frame:

```
df[,my_variables_list] <-  lapply(df[, my_variables_list], as.factor)
```